# Create Home Page presents multiple types of objects and the objects order by date with ASP.Net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, linq, asp.net-core

I'm trying to build a page shown latest contents of the platform. The contents could be from different types (classes), like post, course, comment and more. The contents is ordered by date.

Here is the controller code :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Wall()
{
    CommunityWallViewModel wall = new CommunityWallViewModel()
    {
        Posts = _context.Posts.Include(a => a.Community).Include(a => a.ApplicationUser).Where(a => a.Community.CommunityType == CommunityType.Personal && a.IsHidden == false).OrderByDescending(a => a.DateTime).Take(25).ToList(),
        LatestPublications = _context.Publications.Include(a => a.ApplicationUser)
                                    .OrderByDescending(a => a.PublicationDate)
            .Take(50)
            .ToList(),

        Courses = _context.Courses.Where(c => c.IsFeatured).OrderByDescending(a => a.DateOfRecord),
        FreelancerReadyServices = _context.FreelancerReadyServices.OrderByDescending(a => a.Id).Take(50).ToList(),
        Books = _context.Book.Where(c => c.IsARIDPublications == true && c.IsFeatured == true).ToList(),
    };
    return View(wall);
}
```

Can I do it with ASP.Net framework or any other framework or lang?
Image below demonstrates the page contents how to appear.[image: Page structure]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the codes:

models：

```
public class Comment
    {
        public int CommentId { get; set; }       
        public string CommentContent { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public int RecordId { get; set; }
        public Record CommentRecord { get; set; }
    }
    public class Book
    {
        public Book() {Users = new List<User>();}
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public string Bookname { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
        public List<BookUserRelationShip> bookUserRelationShips { get; set; }

       
    }
    public  class User
    {
        public User() { Books = new List<Book>(); }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
        
        public List<BookUserRelationShip> bookUserRelationShips { get; set; }

    }

    public class BookUserRelationShip
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }        
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public User User { get; set; }       
        public int BookRecordId { get; set; }
        public Record BookRecord { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Record
    {
        public int RecordId { get; set; }
        public DateTime RecordTime { get; set; }
        
        public Comment Comment { get; set; }
        
        public BookUserRelationShip BookUserRelationShip { get; set; }

    }
```

DbContext：

```
public UserRecordDbContext(DbContextOptions<UserRecordDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Book> Book { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Comment> Comment { get; set; }    
    public DbSet<Record> Record { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasMany(user => user.Comments).WithOne(comment => comment.User).HasForeignKey(user => user.CommentId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");

        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>().ToTable("Comment");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Record>().HasOne(record => record.Comment).WithOne(comemnt => comemnt.CommentRecord).HasForeignKey<Comment>(m=>m.RecordId);        
        modelBuilder.Entity<Record>().HasOne(record => record.BookUserRelationShip).WithOne(x => x.BookRecord).HasForeignKey<BookUserRelationShip>(m=>m.BookRecordId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Record>().ToTable("Record");

        modelBuilder.Entity<BookUserRelationShip>().HasKey(x => new { x.BookId, x.UserId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<BookUserRelationShip>().HasOne(x => x.Book).WithMany(x => x.bookUserRelationShips).HasForeignKey(x => x.BookId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<BookUserRelationShip>().HasOne(x => x.User).WithMany(x => x.bookUserRelationShips).HasForeignKey(x => x.UserId);
    }
```

Controller：

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var a1 = _context.Record.Include(m => m.BookUserRelationShip.User).Include(m => m.BookUserRelationShip.Book).Include(m => m.Comment.User).ToList();
            a1.Reverse();
            return View(a1);
        }
```

View:

```
@model List<Record>
@foreach (var a in Model)
{
    if (a.Comment != null && a.BookUserRelationShip == null)
    {
        <a>@a.RecordTime</a>
        <br />
        <a>@a.Comment.User.UserName commented:@a.Comment.CommentContent</a>
        <br />
        <br />
    }
    if (a.Comment == null && a.BookUserRelationShip != null)
    {
        <a>@a.RecordTime</a>
        <br />
        <a>@a.BookUserRelationShip.User.UserName added new book( @a.BookUserRelationShip.Book.Bookname )</a>
        <br />
        <br />
    }
}
```

DataBase:

[image: DB1]
[image: DB2]
[image: DB3]
[image: DB4]
[image: DB5]

Result:
[image: Result]